# How to validate if my Purchase already has a Dispute or not. Purchase's Model has no disputes, but Dispute's has Purchase

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, socket.io

How to validate if my Purchase already has a Dispute or not. Purchase's Model has no disputes, but Dispute's has Purchase. I'm using socket.io.

```
socket.on(
    "new cause",
    async (purchase, userId, msgCause, sellerId, callback, res) => {
      if (!msgCause || msgCause === "") {
        return callback({ error: true });
      }

      const disputeExist = await Dispute.findOne({ purchaseId: purchase }).populate({ path: 'purchaseId' }).lean();

      var erros = [];
      if ( purchase == disputeExist.purchaseId ) { 
        erros.push({ text: "Dispute already exist" });
      }
      if (erros.length > 0) {
        res.render("user/chat", { erros });
      } else {
        const dispute = await new Dispute({
          buyer: userId,
          seller: sellerId,
          purchaseId: purchase,
          message: msgCause,
        }).save();
        if (!dispute) {
          return callback({ error: true, message: "dispute save error" });
        }

        const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: userId },
          { $push: { disputes: dispute._id } }
        ).lean();
        if (!user) {
          return callback({ error: true, message: "user save error" });
        }

        //io.to(purchase).emit("chat message", new Date().toLocaleString("en-us") + msgCause);
        callback({ error: false });
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: You seem to already be trying to do the obvious thing, which would be to search available Disputes looking for a reference to the Purchase in question.  What is your code doing?  What do you think it should be doing but isn't?  Maybe someone can look only at your code and see what is going wrong, but you'll have a better chance of getting a useful response if you can tell us more about your environment and the behavior you're getting from your code.

Comment: I'm trying to create a dispute based on purchase, but you can't create more than one dispute, so I need validation